# Organizing code that is repeated for a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Rights now I have a view that displays certain information about places. The information that is displayed has the same properties such as name, address, phone number but with different strings attached for the respected item. What would be the best way of going about organizing this code, so that is more concise?

Here is the code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayView()
    }

    func displayView() {

        if placeNameText == "place 1" {
            addressLabel?.text = "peel lane"
            phoneNumberLabel?.text = "(367) 228-1673"
        }

        if placeNameText == "place 2" {
            addressLabel?.text = "park avenue"
            phoneNumberLabel?.text = "(408) 356-7778"
        }

        if placeNameText == "place 3" {
            addressLabel?.text = "town circle"
            phoneNumberLabel?.text = "(813) 849-4493"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the code is very repetitive. Is there a way to make this cleaner?

Comment: You could consider using a switch statement instead of multiple conditionals. That would speed up execution a little bit too. Aside from that, your code doesn't look very repetitive to me.

Comment: Could you share with us how your `ViewController` applies `PlacesDetailView`?

Comment: Thanks for that comment.     The PlacesDetailView doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the actual data to a model like a `struct` or `Object` then pass it to `displayView`. This works well because `displayView` will always do the same thing.

```
struct Place {
    let name: String
    let phoneNumber: String
}

func displayView(place: Place) {
  addressLabel?.text = place.name
  phoneNumberLabel?.text = place.phoneNumber
}
```